# my java output occuring twice when adding a method?

Tags: java

when i run the code it works fine until i get to the IF statements where i have the choice to enter "1" or "2" and the result displays the next println twice? Im still new to java so any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment{ 
public static void main ( String[] args ) {

    Assignment game;
    game = new Assignment();
    game.darkJungle();
    game.oldBridge();
    game.abandonedShack();}

public void darkJungle() {

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   

    System.out.println("Hello adventurer. You awake from your slumber in a dark jungle, with no 
memory of your past life.");
    System.out.println(""); 


    System.out.println("Before you set off exploring for answers, what do you wish to call 
yourself?");
    String playerName = scanner.next();

    System.out.println("hello " + playerName); 
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Inventory");
    System.out.println("-------------");
    String weapon;
    weapon = "glock";
    boolean rustyKey = true;


    System.out.println(weapon);
    System.out.println("rustyKey");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("You look to the east and west and notice they're the safest looking paths. 
Which path do you set off on?"); 
    System.out.println("1: west");
    System.out.println("2: east");

    int choice;
    choice = scanner.nextInt();


    if(choice==1){
        System.out.println("You have wandered onto a creaky old bridge.");

        oldBridge();}

    if(choice==2) 
        {System.out.println("You find an abandoned shack.");

        abandonedShack();}  


}
public  void oldBridge() {

System.out.println("hello world");  

}
public  void abandonedShack() {


}



}
```

### output looks like this

Hello adventurer. You awake from your slumber in a dark jungle, with no memory of your past life.

Before you set off exploring for answers, what do you wish to call yourself?
john citizen
hello john citizen

Inventory

---

glock
rustyKey

You look to the east and west and notice they're the safest looking paths. Which path do you set off on?
1: west
2: east
1
You have wandered onto a creaky old bridge.
hello world
hello world

When i get to the helloworld part it prints twice. Why is this and how can i fix it?

Comment: You are calling your `oldBridge()` method that prints "hello world" twice. Once directly in the main method, and once inside the `darkJungle()` method if the user enters 1 (which you do).

Answer (score 1):

Your `darkJungle()` method calls your `oldBridge()` method (that prints "hello world"). Right after your main method calls `darkJungle()`, it calls `oldBridge()`. This results in "hello world" being printed twice. Once when `oldBridge()` was called by `darkJungle()`, and once when it was called directly by the main method.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. how do i fix from happening twice. sorry if its obvious im really new to java.